# Set of uncorrelated cognitive tests for self quantification and tracking

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, test

I self track partly to optimize intelligence and productivity. Cognitive tests are good proxy of both. I tried all the tests in "time of day" experiment at [quantified-mind](http://www.quantified-mind.com/) and many seem to test the same thing. I would like to select a smaller subset of them so that I am not retesting the same underlying abilities multiple times but ideally not miss any either. Are there any studies about correlation of such tests or even formal batteries that I could perform at home for little cost?